# Mechanism to prevent "flood" for a websocket

Tags: java, websocket, client-server

I am writing a web application that makes intense use of websockets (standard JSR implementation).

Through the websocket I exchange information.

A Client sends a request (JSON) to the Server, the Server decodes the message and sends some info back (JSON).

How can avoid maliciously client to flood my Server with requests. For example I want to limit the number of requests at 10 every 5 seconds (what I mean by request is the certain JSON message the client is sending in order to get the information).

Is there are built-in-way of doing this or I have to write my own mechanism ?

Comment: take a look at leaky bucket algorithms

Comment: There's nothing there at the WebSocket level, and I doubt that the WebSocket implementation you use on the server provides anything like that (though it can't hurt to look in the documentation).

Comment: @andrucz that would be super useful, but for an application with a lot clients wouldn't be overkill to keep a thread for each client ? i am asking that because i think i need to keep a bucker for every individual client, and to each bucket i need to associate a thread.